# In WPF, is OnLostKeyboardFocus guaranteed to be called after OnGotKeyboardFocus?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have code that looks like this:

```
  class MyUserControl : Control { ...
    protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);

        StartDoingSomethingRisky()
    }

    protected override void OnLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostKeyboardFocus(e);

        StopDoingSomethingRisky();
    }
```

Should I be worried that in some circumstances I may continue the risky operation even after MyUserControl has disappeared, or have I covered 100% of cases?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can see going wrong with this is the fact that you are not checking which element has "lost" focus.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostkeyboardfocus.aspx:
Because this event uses bubbling routing, the element that lost focus might be a child element instead of the element where the event handler is actually attached. Check the Source in the event data to determine the actual element that lost focus.

If you are making something happen when a particular element has gained focus and stop happening when it loses focus then you will need to check the args passed in to see what called the event.

Hope that helps